# Very fast and efficient way to check that contents of the directory weren't modified

Tags: linux, algorithm, steganography

I need a way of determining whether contents of a folder containing some executable stuff have not been modified in any way a moment before I decide to execute the whatever is in it. Check every time before executing.

The problem is I am very limited in terms of time (the check has to be make nearly instantly, something like 100ms would be too much for this particular case) and a bit in computational power (running the whole thing on just a computer that's got a bunch of other stuff happening on it - internet browsing, music playing, whatever).

Talking about a Linux machine. The size of the folders would be up to 6MB worst case.

My primary idea was to have some kind of checksums-map-storing-file kept somewhere encrypted, and comparing a newly calculated value with the stored one. I do not have a big concern about storing the checksum-file. I do have a concern about using an efficient algorithm that lets me be as sure as possible that the files weren't modified.

Suggestions? Would it be safe enough to, say, only look into the files' metadata? or would checking the contents matter each time as well?

The algorithm I will be using is safe with me - I can kind of be sure that the "intruder" cannot "know" it, so its not my worry.

I feel like steganography could come in handy here, but I just can't figure out a possible useful way for it here.

Comment: Sounds like a job for [md5sum](http://askubuntu.com/questions/318530/generate-md5-checksum-for-all-files-in-a-directory). For a 6 MB directory you would rarely see > 100 ms on any decent hardware

Comment: Are you worried about the file being modified between your check and executing the file? It would take some good timing, but is possible

Comment: @NeilSmithline, I actually am not worried about that.

Comment: @Jedi will do some benchmarking so see how the timing does for my case.

Comment: On a [t2.nano](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/ec2-update-t2-nano-instances-now-available/) with the default magnetic disk, a 12 MB directory with 115 files takes ~100ms real time to generate and about 90ms real time to check. Measured using [time](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52313/how-to-get-execution-time-of-a-script-effectively).

Comment: Why do you think steganography will be useful?  Do you trust the metadata (e.g. modification times)? What's your threat model?

Comment: What kinds of modifications are you worried about? Someone modifying the file through the running operating system? Someone modifying the disk contents by mounting the disk on another machine while the system is powered off? Do you need only integrity breach detection, or also availability, i.e. is it acceptable if you start processing some valid data and only then detect that part of the not-yet-processed data is corrupted?

Comment: @Jedi instead of keeping a separate file with the mapping of all the checksums/whatsoever I could just store each instance of such data *somewhere* (that's the center of my stego-idea) in each folder. And since its a part of the algorithm I can expect that the intruder wouldn't know where it is.

Comment: @Gilles well, they could mess with the files -  modify some code in them to make it do what they need it to do. 
- is it acceptable if you start processing some valid data and only then detect that part of the not-yet-processed data is corrupted?  --- no, I need to know if anything was externally (by *intruder*) modified before the launch so I can prohibit it.
- Someone modifying the disk contents by mounting the disk on another machine while the system is powered off -- yes, that is my main concern

Comment: @niralittle security-by-obscurity is almost always a idea as your primary safeguard (in this case if an attacker finds your hidden file, how will you know?).

Comment: hmm, I kinda see how that just wouldn't work for me. Crap :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply use `md5sum`.

First keep a copy of the current checksum:

```
md5sum /path/to/files/* > /path/to/safedirectory/checksum
```

Then you can run the following to check for differences:

```
md5sum /path/to/files/*|diff /path/to/safedirectory/checksum -
```

An alternative proposed by @Jedi is to use the `-c` option:

```
md5sum -c /path/to/safedirectory/checksum
```

Comment: @Jedi:  It is a pretty nice alternative, so I'll include it in my answer.

Comment: @Jedi `md5sum -c` will not point out new files added in the directory.

Comment: @AlexStragies good point. `-c` ensures that the files that you want to validate are tracked and checked. It's neater than a diff, but it boils down to OP's use case.

Answer (score 0):

Create a visually recognizable fingerprint based on the shasum, and use it for verification.

```
$ bishop $(find| LC_ALL=C sort|tar -cf - -T - --no-recursion|shasum|tr -d ' -')
+--[ RandomArt ]--+
| .. ooooo        |
|  Eo . .         |
|  .   .          |
|       .         |
|        S o      |
|         o Oo.   |
|          +.Xo   |
|          .* o*  |
|          o+=Bo. |
+-----------------+
```

Get [bishop here](https://askubuntu.com/a/630679/545309)